# XML Schema union ignore whiteSpace property

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

According to [XML Schema specification of whitespace](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dt-whiteSpace):

> For all datatypes ·derived· by ·union·  whiteSpace does not apply directly; however, **the normalization behavior of ·union· types is controlled by the value of whiteSpace on that one of the ·memberTypes· against which the ·union· is successfully validated**.

and

> **for string the value of whiteSpace is preserve**

**Based on that**, the following example should not be valid as the whitespace of the string should be preserved, and the pattern should not be satisfied. However its valid. So, my querstion is **¿why is this XML valid against this schema?**

XML (notice the whitesepaces):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<elem>  Hello           world</elem>
```

XML Schema (notice the pattern restriction):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:simpleType name="myUnion">
        <xs:union memberTypes="xs:string">
        </xs:union>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:element name="elem">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="myUnion">
                <xs:pattern value="Hello world" />
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

---

**EDIT :** Xerces says its valid, Saxon says its not valid. Thats seems to be a Xerces bug.

However, if we define the union like this:

```
<xs:simpleType name="myUnion">
    <xs:union>
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:whiteSpace value="collapse"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:union>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Again, Xerces says its valid, Saxon says its not valid. But this time its seems to be a Saxon bug (as the whitespace should be collapsed and the pattern should be satisfied). ¿What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Who says it's valid?

Saxon says:

```
Processing file:/Users/mike/Desktop/temp/test.xml
Validation error on line 2 of test.xml:
  XSD: The content "  Hello           world" of element <elem> does not match the required
  simple type. Value "  Hello           world" contravenes the pattern facet "Hello world"
  of the type of element elem
  Validating /elem[1]
  See http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#cvc-datatype-valid clause 1
Validation error on line 2 column 37 of test.xml:
  XSD: One or more validation errors were reported
Validation unsuccessful
```

and Saxon usually gets it right ;-)

Comment: Take a look at the new example in which Saxon seems to be the wrong one and Xerces seems to be right.

Comment: Yes, I think you are probably right. I'm actually finding it hard to find definitive text in XSD part 2 that ties this together: the pattern facet is defined to operate on a "value in the lexical space", and the whitespace facet determines the "normalized value"; I'm not 100% sure that these are the same thing. However, Part 1 makes it pretty clear that it is the normalized value that must be valid against the constraints, so I guess the stuff about the pattern being applied to the lexical space has just failed to pick up that terminology.

Comment: Thank you. Marked as accepted as my first example should not be valid, Xerces validator was wrong. It seems that something similar happens to the enumeration facet, that can also be present when restricting a simpleType derived from union, and maybe the same happens for assertions in XSD 1.1.

Comment: **I've found another Saxon bug**, now in Saxon - EE 9.6.0.5 : in XSD, given a xs:simpleType defined using xs:restriction, **Saxon fails if the xs:restriction node contains both an xs:assertion and a xs:enumeration**. It fails trying to validate the enumeration facet against the assertion giving the following error: `Validation context required`. In order to reproduce this error you can add this element to an XML Schema: `<element name="e"><simpleType><restriction base="string"><enumeration value="v"/><assertion test="$value = 'v'"/></restriction></simpleType></element>`. Please confirm bug.

Comment: Thanks. I'm sorry, I know this is not the proper site to report bugs but I don't use saxon mailing list nor I am registered saxon user.

Comment: You're welcome to log it here and we'll pick it up if we notice it, but we manage resolution through our own bug tracker and you won't get feedback on progress unless you visit that tracker.